# How to detect if a printer is conected with pyqt?

Tags: python, printing, pyqt4

I'm programming in Linux a windows application. In this moment I need a solution to detect if the default printer is connected.
I have the next code:

```
def mPrint(self, value):
    font = QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)

    self.mEditor = QTextEdit()
    self.mEditor.setFont(font)

    self.printer = QPrinter(QPrinterInfo.defaultPrinter())
    self.printer.setColorMode(QPrinter.GrayScale)
    self.printer.setPageMargins(7, 20, 7, 7, QPrinter.Millimeter)
    self.printer.setOrientation(QPrinter.Portrait)

    try:
        if value == 1:
            self.printCommand()
        else:
            self.printDelivery()
    except self.printer.Error as e:
        print(e)
```

with QPrinterInfo I can get the default printer and know if it exists.

```
QPrinterInfo.defaultPrinter().isNull()
```

but it always returns true, because I have a default printer in my PC but if it is not connected, everything goes to the printer queue.

Does anyone knows how to recognize if the printer is connected and how to show a Qmessage if there is an exception?

Comment: If `QPrinter.printerState()` doesn't return something useful that I would suggest looking at other Python libraries you might be able to use for checking the printer state.

Comment: I tried use printerState() but always returns 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution:

```
 self.mEditor = QTextEdit()
 self.mEditor.setFont(font)

 self.printer = QPrinter(QPrinterInfo.defaultPrinter())
 self.mEditor.document().print_(self.printer)
```